# Why does my build break when importing a class from a shared package in my monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, yarn-workspaces, turborepo

I have a monorepo using turborepo with yarn as the package manager. I have the typical directory structure of a handful of frontend React based applications and some shared packages such as a UI system, types and various configs.

I came across a strange issue which took a while to pinpoint..

Amongst my shared types, I declared a class definition which implements one of the types or some of its respective subtypes.

I exported the class definition along with the types, which were previously working correctly when imported and consumed by both my React App packages, and my shared UI package.

Upon importing the newly defined class, and then instantiating it in my component, the hot rebuild process of the React App fails. I can also try and instantiate the class in my shared UI package which yields the same error, but also causes the React App build to fail (as it depends upon the UI package also).

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Report.js 55:22-41
export 'WrittenConsultation' (imported as 'WrittenConsultation') was not found in '@namespace/types' (module has no exports)
 
ERROR in ../../packages/types/src/index.ts 6:0-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './unicons' in '/Users/charlietimlin/Documents/localDevelopment/tbl/packages/types/src'

ERROR in ../../packages/types/src/index.ts 7:0-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './db' in '/Users/charlietimlin/Documents/localDevelopment/tbl/packages/types/src'

ERROR in ../../packages/types/src/index.ts 8:0-23
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './misc' in '/Users/charlietimlin/Documents/localDevelopment/tbl/packages/types/src'

ERROR in ../../packages/types/src/index.ts 9:0-21
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ui' in '/Users/charlietimlin/Documents/localDevelopment/tbl/packages/types/src'
 
ERROR in ../../packages/types/src/index.ts 10:0-27
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './consults' in '/Users/charlietimlin/Documents/localDevelopment/tbl/packages/types/src'
```

The React app is being run in development mode. The types directory is pictured in the attached image. Below is the `tsconfig.json` for the types.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

Everything works fine until instantiating the class, when the React App build / dev process fails and can no longer resolve the paths to any of the type files, despite the class being declared inside `consults.d.ts` whose contents is below, where `WrittenConsultation` is the offending class.

```
/**
 * Written Consultations
 */

import { BiomarkerGroupT, BiomarkerT } from './db';

export type WrittenConsultResponseAbbreviationT =
  | 'high'
  | 'low'
  | 'meds'
  | 'also'
  | 'ipeds';

interface GenderSpecificTextFieldT {
  male: string;
  female: string;
}
interface WrittenConsultHighResponseT {
  name: 'High due to';
  abbreviation: 'high';
  response: GenderSpecificTextFieldT;
}
interface WrittenConsultLowResponseT {
  name: 'Low due to';
  abbreviation: 'low';
  response: GenderSpecificTextFieldT;
}
interface WrittenConsultMedicationsResponseT {
  name: 'Medications that can interact with biomarker';
  abbreviation: 'meds';
  response: GenderSpecificTextFieldT;
}
interface WrittenConsultAlsoAffectedByResponseT {
  name: 'Also affected by';
  abbreviation: 'also';
  response: GenderSpecificTextFieldT;
}
interface WrittenConsultIpedsResponseT {
  name: 'IPEDS that can interact with biomarker';
  abbreviation: 'ipeds';
  response: GenderSpecificTextFieldT;
}

export type WrittenConsultationDefaultResponseT =
  | WrittenConsultHighResponseT
  | WrittenConsultLowResponseT
  | WrittenConsultMedicationsResponseT
  | WrittenConsultAlsoAffectedByResponseT
  | WrittenConsultIpedsResponseT;

// KEYED BY BIOMARKER ID
export type WrittenConsultationReponsesObjectT = {
  [key: BiomarkerT['uid']]: string;
};

export type WrittenConsultConcernColorT = 'red' | 'amber' | 'green';

export interface WrittenConsultationT {
  consultant_name: string;
  consultant_id: string;
  responses: WrittenConsultationReponsesObjectT;
  concerns: {
    [key: BiomarkerGroupT['uid']]: WrittenConsultConcernColorT;
  };
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  last_updated_by: string;
}

export class WrittenConsultation {
  consultant_name: string;
  consultant_id: string;
  responses: WrittenConsultationReponsesObjectT;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at: string;
  last_updated_by: string;

  constructor(consultantName: string, consultantId: string) {
    this.consultant_name = consultantName;
    this.consultant_id = consultantId;
    this.responses = {};
    this.created_at = new Date().toISOString();
    this.updated_at = new Date().toISOString();
    this.last_updated_by = consultantId;
  }
}
```

I am presuming there is some incompatibility with TS, JS, Node versions etc but I have no idea where to start as they are the only errors and information that are logged to the console on failure.